# ReplaceAll with Powers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching, semantic-matching

If I run the following code:

```
a^2/b^2 /. {a/b -> c}
```

I'm getting output:

```
a^2/b^2
```

How can I obtain `c^2`? How to generalize this problem for any powers?

Comment: If you want using rules, you have to look at the "FullForm" of the expression

Comment: This is such a common issue, and hence I *know* that there are numerous duplicates on this site, but I have no idea how to find them.  Perhaps someone knows of one?

Comment: @march See my last comment :) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about

```
a^2/b^2 /.a->b c
(*c^2*)
```